# Is it possible to set foreign key to null without HasMany?

Tags: c#, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have entity Territory

```
    class Territory
    {
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string Title {get;set;}
    }
```

and some entities which have references to it, such as

```
    class MyObject
    {
      public Territory Territory {get;set;}
    }
```

and mapping in FluentNHibernate

```
    References(x => x.Territory)
            .Column("TerritoryId")
            .Nullable()                
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.None();
```

and when I'm deleting territory I have error: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK377ABC4DAD038F1B". The conflict occurred in database "GPM_Test", table "dbo.MyObject", column 'TerritoryId'.

How can I make nhibernate set FK to NULL before territory is deleted?

I need something like in SQL

```
    ON DELETE set NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you have to delete the links between the entities first before you can delete the object itself, this can ofcourse be done in the database by cascade deletion. Another way is to programmicaly removed the links between the entity you want to remove and the related tables.

Comment: So I need to write myObject.Territory = null before I delete my territory entity and how i can manage with all my entities reference territory?

Comment: I don't know about your database design, but as I understand it's a direct link. So first update the all objects which have Territory ID set to the territory you would like to remove.

The linq statement could look something like: 
    `context.MyObject.Where(obj => obj.TerritoryId == [TerritoyID_to_remove])`